# Get data from Mysql and convert into PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I hope to get some help on a problem that I suppose must be simple but I have been stuck for a while.

I have a simple Mysql table with 3 fields ( id, customer, sales ) . All I need is to query this table and get an php array.

Here's my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mysqltable";    
$result = $mysqli->query($query))
```

I need to write a code to loop and get an array in this format:

```
$row=array(0=>"500,200",1=>"500,300",2=>"1000,600",3=>"800,400",4=>"200,500");
```

So I can end with

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

Would appreciate any help to solve this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: `while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){ $row->sales }`

Comment: Hi, This was my first question here. Maybe I wasn't clear about my question... but I have written the code but simply can't get the output array format I need. I have also looked in other answers...sure doing my homework !

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqli_fetch_all()

```
    mixed mysqli_result::fetch_all ([ int $resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM ] )
```

or

```
    mixed mysqli_fetch_all ( mysqli_result $result [, int $resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM ] )
```

for reference read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

also there is

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row)
{
echo $row['CountryCode'];
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you hasnainwasaya. What if I need to get 2 fields from Mysql instead of one ( 'CountryCode' and 'CityCode' for ex) ?