# how to compare 2 tables and create a new table and update daily

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, denormalization

```
table1

----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      email          |     selection1   | selection2        |     selection3
|                                                           
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|  test@test.com      |        4       |           7                     9
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|
|test2@test.com                2                     9                6
---------------------|------------------|--------------------|-------------------|      

table2
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      race1|                 race2      |         race3     |       race4
|                                                           
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|  5                   |        7       |           9                    2
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|
```

So, I have two tables.
One is based on user input selecting 3 races for the number of the winner.

The second table is the number of the race winner.

I want to compare the two tables and create a third table. If the person's selection matches the winning race then they receive 50 points. So the third table would display "email" and "points"

This will continue for 4 days so if the same email matches another race winner they gain an extra 50 points.

I've tried INNER JOIN, but there are too many combinations. I'm new to PHP and SQL, so I really don't know what approach to take.

Comment: You should normalize the tables

Comment: this DB structure is a total mess. what if you need 50 races, you will change the second table's structure? and how user selections are corresponding with these races, like: `selection1 = 2` in `table1`, but in `table2` you have `race4 = 2`, so is this means that the user wins or not?

Comment: Basically the top table will be user input, so they give their email address, then pick their selections for the 3 races (only 3).
table 2 is the results for each race. so if race 1 =1, and the users selection1 =1. they receive 50 points. if race 2 matches their selection2 they again a further 50points. hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the values out of the database, then loop through each user and compare their submissions to the results in the second table. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554868/get-data-from-mysql-and-convert-into-php-array) should be able to help you with the first part (pulling the data out of MySQL and into arrays).

Then let's say that after pulling them out of the database that you have a $users array with all of the users and their submissions, then a $results array with the winners for each race (table2's contents). You can then use a for loop or foreach to go through each user and compare each of their selections to the results. Something like this, for example:

```
<?
//Loop through each of the users in the $users array
foreach($users as $user)
{
    if($user['selection1'] == $results['race1'])
    {
        //Add to their points or whatever you would like to do
    }

    if($user['selection2'] == $results['race2'])
    {
        //Add to their points or whatever you would like to do
    }

    if($user['selection3'] == $results['race3'])
    {
        //Add to their points or whatever you would like to do
    }
}

?>
```

However all that being said, you may want to look at re-organizing your database structure. As it is this isn't very flexible if you want to change things in the future. Also the example you provided has 3 races in the first table but 4 in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Your first task is to create a subquery that delivers your `table1` in the form of email, selection.  That looks like this (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mbXAqAo6Y4MPd3jH9vAY4Q/0)

```
             SELECT email, selection1 AS selection FROM table1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT email, selection2 AS selection FROM table1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT email, selection3 AS selection FROM table1
```

Next, do the same for your table2. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mbXAqAo6Y4MPd3jH9vAY4Q/1)

```
             SELECT race1 AS race from table2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT race2 AS race from table2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT race3 AS race from table2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT race4 AS race from table2;
```

Then, you need to figure out how many `race` values match each `selection` value. That takes an aggregate function.  The outline of your query is

```
   SELECT email, COUNT(race) races_chosen
     FROM selections
     JOIN races ON selections.selection = races.race
    GROUP BY email
```

Here, with the JOIN operation you're creating a result set that shows each email along with a selection that also turned up in the races. Then you're counting them.

The actual query here needs to use your subqueries.  It looks like this. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mbXAqAo6Y4MPd3jH9vAY4Q/2)

```
   SELECT email, COUNT(race) races_chosen
     FROM (
             SELECT email, selection1 AS selection FROM table1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT email, selection2 AS selection FROM table1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT email, selection3 AS selection FROM table1

          ) selections
     JOIN (
             SELECT race1 AS race from table2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT race2 AS race from table2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT race3 AS race from table2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT race4 AS race from table2
          ) AS races ON selections.selection = races.race
    GROUP BY email
```

Finally, you can change your SELECT line to this to get your points. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mbXAqAo6Y4MPd3jH9vAY4Q/3)

```
   SELECT email, COUNT(race) races_chosen, COUNT(races)*50 points
```

A couple of things for you to consider.

1. Don't create another table to contain this result data.  Instead, use the query to generate it whenever you need it. That's easier because you don't have to figure out what changed to update your extra table; you just generate the results on the fly. SQL is made for that kind of operation.
2. The subqueries I gave you to use had the effect of taking your [denormalized](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/N/normalization.html) tables and normalizing them. Without denormalizing them, the query to generate your results would have been much more complex.  Your tables are denormalized because they contain multiple facts on each row.

Here's what I mean. Your table2 uses one row to show four different races. Instead you should have one row per race. Then it's much easier to add another race to the table with an INSERT, or to remove one with a DELETE.  It also makes the query easier.

Your `table1` is denormalized because it's a way to enforce your rule that each email address may pick up to three races. That's a tolerable software design decision. But, if you want to let them add a fourth race in the future, fixing your app gets harder.